# Email form saves session variables but doesn't update form inputs properly after refresh

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I just tried out ChatGPT to make an email form, and it worked surprisingly well. However, I ran into some trouble when I wanted the form inputs to keep whatever was written there during last user session. It does show *one* previous input, but it does not change to the most recent input between refresh / captcha failure. Everything else works as intended. So, what is wrong with this code here?

**index.php**

```php
<?php
session_start(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>mail form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="send-email.php">
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '' ?>"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : '' ?>" required><br>
    <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
    <textarea id="message" name="message"><?php echo isset($_SESSION['message']) ? $_SESSION['message'] : '' ?></textarea><br><br>

    <!-- CAPTCHA image and input field -->
    <img src="captcha.php" alt="CAPTCHA image"><br>
    <label for="captcha">Enter the text from the image:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
</form>

<?php
    // Check if there is an error code in the URL
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        // Get the error code from the URL
        $error = $_GET['error'];

        // Display an error message based on the error code
        if ($error == 'captcha') {
            echo '<p>The CAPTCHA is incorrect. Please try again.</p>';
        }
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**send-email.php**

```php
<?php
    // Get the form data
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Set session variables
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
     $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
     $_SESSION['message'] = $_POST['message'];
    }

    // Get the user's input for the CAPTCHA
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

    // Check if the CAPTCHA is correct
    if ($captcha != 'unicorn') {
        // The CAPTCHA is incorrect, so redirect the user to the form with an error code
        header('Location: index.php?error=captcha');
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address
    $to = 'email@example.com';

    // Set the email subject
    $subject = 'New email from contact form';

    // Build the email content
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email
    mail($to, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);

    // Redirect to the index.html page with success code
    header('Location: index.php?success=1');
?>
```

**captcha.php**

```php
<?php
    // Set the content type to image/png
    header('Content-type: image/png');

    // Create a blank image and add some text
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5, 'unicorn', $text_color);

    // Output the image
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Can you reduce the code to the minimal parts neccessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's code generated by chatGPT

Comment: `if ($captcha != 'unicorn')`...what's the point of a captcha if the value is the same every time?

Comment: @Synchro [as far as I can see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) the ban is on using chatGPT to generate answers. I don't see why someone shouldn't ask a _question_ about a bug in some code it generated, as long as the question is otherwise on-topic.

Comment: `$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";`...this will result in spoofing the sender's email address, and is quite likely to mean recipient mailservers drop the message as spam / faking, and/or result in your mailserver being blacklisted, if you do it a lot. Use a fixed "from" field which is an email address on the same domain as your mailserver (it doesn't necessary need a mailbox attached, it can be a "no-reply@example.com" type of thing), and if you need to see the email address submitted from the form, you can put it in the email body and/or in the reply-to header.

Comment: Please create a [mre] so that it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: @DonaldDuck why would you say that this isn't one? It seems to cover all the aspects of what's being asked. What's missing?

Comment: @ADyson It's complete, but it's not minimal.

Answer (score 2):

This code achieves nothing at all:

```php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
  // set the session variables
  $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
  $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
  $_SESSION['message'] = $_POST['message'];
  // ...
session_unset();
}
```

It sets a bunch of session values – and then promptly [unsets them all again](https://www.php.net/session_unset). Not surprisingly, this results in an empty session.

Given your problem description is essentially "stuff is disappearing from my session", you should perhaps be looking for things that might possibly be removing things from your session, like say, calling a function called `session_unset`.

This is why we can't depend on chatGPT; it's great at producing perfectly plausible but subtly incoherent results.

Comment: Also worth pointing out, this code is in the wrong file too - the form is posted to send-email.php, so this code will never even run, because a form is never POSTed to the index page

Comment: @ADyson but the user is redirected back to that page at the end of `send-email.php`

Comment: @NicoHaase yeah, but that's a GET not a POST, because redirects are always GETs. So it wouldn't make `if (isset($_POST['send']))` true.

Comment: @ADyson you're right....

Comment: Actually, that session_unset(); was just something I tried when trying to solve it. Forgot to remove it when posting my code here, woops. Problem still remains with/without it.

Comment: @eskilla pay attention to my comment just under this answer, too :-)

Comment: @ADyson I did, and I appreciate it. But I tried that and it didn't solve it.

Comment: @eskilla why did you change it to `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` in the process though? That wasn't suggested, and is counterproductive - the form contains a button with `name="send"`, not `name="submit"`.